# Linebreak in the string so it doesn't leave the box

Tags: javascript, php, xml

In order to understand my problem see this:

http://home.htw-berlin.de/~s0544437/quiztes2t.php?p=7

the question is coming from an XML data and it should have a line break as soon as it is too long to fit in the grey box. I've tried a couple of things and nothing worked.

I don't need a dynamic solution if it's easier to solve the problem by adding the line breaks in the XML manually for every question, but I don't know how.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>

        <style>
            body {background-image:url('bgimg.jpg');
            background-size:100%;}

            #ccontainer{
                width:550px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                margin-top:100px;
            }
        </style>

        <script>
            window.onload = function(){
                var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
                var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                var quizbg = new Image();
                var Question = new String;
                var Option1 = new String;
                var Option2 = new String;
                var Option3 = new String;
                var mx = 0;
                var my = 0;
                var CorrectAnswer = 0;
                var qnumber = 0;
                var rightanswers = 0;
                var wronganswers = 0;
                var QuizFinished = false;
                var lock = false;
                var textpos1 = 45;
                var textpos2 = 145;
                var textpos3 = 230;
                var textpos4 = 325;
                var Questions = new Array;
                var Options = new Array;
                var textArray = new Array('line2', 'line3', 'line4', 'line5');
                var rows = 98;

                <?php
                    $datastr = "data".$_GET["p"].".xml";
                    $xml = simplexml_load_file($datastr);
                    $counter= count($xml);
                    for($i=0;$i<$counter;$i++){
                    echo "Questions[".$i."]='".$xml-> task[$i]->question ."';";
                    echo "\n";
                    echo "Options[".$i."]=['".$xml-> task[$i]->option[0] ."','";
                    echo $xml-> task[$i]->option[1] ."','";
                    echo $xml-> task[$i]->option[2]."'];";
                    echo "\n";
                    }
                ?>

                quizbg.onload = function(){
                    context.drawImage(quizbg, 0, 0);
                    SetQuestions();
                }//Spiel Hintergrund
                quizbg.src = "quizbg2.png";

                SetQuestions = function(){
                    Question=Questions[qnumber];
                    CorrectAnswer=1+Math.floor(Math.random()*3);

                    if(CorrectAnswer==1){Option1=Options[qnumber][0];Option2=Options[qnumber][1];Option3=Options[qnumber][2];}
                    if(CorrectAnswer==2){Option1=Options[qnumber][2];Option2=Options[qnumber][0];Option3=Options[qnumber][1];}
                    if(CorrectAnswer==3){Option1=Options[qnumber][1];Option2=Options[qnumber][2];Option3=Options[qnumber][0];}

                    context.textBaseline = "middle";
                    context.font = "18pt Calibri,Arial";
                    context.fillText(Question,20,textpos1);
                    context.font = "18pt Calibri,Arial";
                    context.fillText(Option1,20,textpos2);
                    context.fillText(Option2,20,textpos3);
                    context.fillText(Option3,20,textpos4);
                }//Erzeugt Fragen

                canvas.addEventListener('click',ProcessClick,false);

                function ProcessClick(ev) {
                    mx=ev.x-canvas.offsetLeft;
                    my=ev.y-canvas.offsetTop;

                    if(ev.x == undefined){
                        mx = ev.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
                        my = ev.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
                    }

                    if(lock){
                        ResetQ();
                    }//if lock

                    else{
                        if(my>110 && my<180){GetFeedback(1);}
                        if(my>200 && my<270){GetFeedback(2);}
                        if(my>290 && my<360){GetFeedback(3);}
                    }//!lock
                }//ProcessClick

                GetFeedback = function(a){
                    if(a==CorrectAnswer){
                        document.getElementById('ra').play();
                        context.drawImage(quizbg, 0,400,75,70,480,110+(90*(a-1)),75,70);
                        rightanswers++;//drawImage(image, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight)
                    }

                    else{
                        document.getElementById('wa').play();
                        context.drawImage(quizbg, 75,400,75,70,480,110+(90*(a-1)),75,70);
                        wronganswers++;
                    }

                    lock=true;
                    context.font = "14pt Calibri,Arial";
                    context.fillText("Nochmal Klicken zur nächsten Frage ",20,380);
                }//get feedback

                ResetQ= function(){
                    lock=false;
                    context.clearRect(0,0,550,400);
                    qnumber++;
                    if(qnumber==Questions.length){
                        EndQuiz();
                    }

                    else{
                        context.drawImage(quizbg, 0, 0);
                        SetQuestions();
                    }
                }

                EndQuiz=function(){
                    canvas.removeEventListener('click',ProcessClick,false);
                    context.drawImage(quizbg, 0,0,550,90,0,0,550,400);
                    context.font = "20pt Calibri,Arial";
                    context.fillText("Deine Prüfung ist vorbei!",20,100);
                    context.font = "16pt Calibri,Arial";
                    context.fillText("Richtige Antworten: "+String(rightanswers),20,200);
                    context.fillText("Falsche Antworten: "+String(wronganswers),20,240);
                }
            };// Läd das Spiel
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <audio src="righta.mp3" id="ra"></audio>
        <audio src="wronga2.mp3" id="wa"></audio>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#show").click(function() {
                    $("p").toggle();
                });
            });// zeigt/versteckt hintergrund musikplayer wenn versteckt/offen
        </script>

        <button id="show">Musik</button>

        <p hidden>
            <audio controls autoplay controls loop>
                <source src="Hitman Blood Money - Jesper Kyd - Amb Zone.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
            </audio>
        </p>

        <div id="ccontainer">
            <canvas id="myCanvas" width="550" height="400"></canvas>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is how the XML looks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> 
<All>         
        <task>
              <question>Question here if too long leavs the box like this asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd</question>
              <option>need a line break</option>
              <option>option 2</option>
              <option>option 3</option>
        </task>  
</All>
```

Comment: try <br/> instead of \n ;

Comment: sounds like a homework.

Comment: <br/> an \n dont work and its not a homework